# Does this activation of carbonyls usually involve a SN1 or a SN2?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

The process I have seen in class to activate a carbonyl function is acetalisation.

One of the steps involved is the following :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WA0W7bC.png]

So I was wondering, is that a $\ce{S_{N}1}$ or a $\ce{S_{N}2}$ ?

(PS : drawing molecules with paint is awful, anyone knows a good free molecules drawer ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an $\ce{S_{N}1}$ or an $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction.  It is commonly referred to as an "addition-elimination" reaction.  You've drawn the key piece of evidence in your diagram - the tetrahedral intermediate.  Not an $\ce{S_{N}1}$ reaction because there is no carbonium ion formed in this reaction.  This is evidenced by many facts such as the lack of carbonium ion type rearrangements when substituents are present alpha to the carbonyl.  Nor is it an $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction, the attacking group does not start to bond and the leaving group does not start to leave and break its bond simultaneously.  Instead there is a real tetrahedral intermediate that exists in equilibrium with the reactant as well as the product.  You "add" a nucleophile to the protonated carbonyl compound to form the tetrahedral intermediate, then you "eliminate" one the substituents in the tetrahedral intermediate and either go back to reactant or forward to product.

[image]

Here's another, more specific drawing for the case at hand.

[image]

Comment: What would be the formula of the tetrahedral intermediate ?

Comment: See the picture I've added to my post.

Comment: where does the =O come from ? where is $R_2$ gone ? (and btw what do you use to draw those molecules?)

Comment: 1) You had the word "carbonyl" in your title, so I assumed you were starting from a carbonyl compound - so I drew one in my diagram, 2) I replaced R2 with X, my drawing is a little more general, If R2 is an alkyl group, then it can't leave and we would just have an equilibrium between the ketal (the tetrahedral intermediate) and the starting ketone, but it is still an example of an "addition-elimination" reaction, 3) I use ChemSketch freeware for my drawings

Comment: Here is the acetalisation i'm talking about http://i.gyazo.com/351823bdf8c4b8437ae81ec6302ee407.png

Comment: Since you're starting with a ketone, the reaction is called ketalization.  The final product, the ketal, is in equilibrium with the starting ketone.  For most ketones the equilibrium lies far to the ketone side (not much ketal present).  Still, for the reasons I presented above, it is an addition-elimination reaction that proceeds through a tetrahedral intermediate.

Comment: I read that the IUPAC wanted us to stop using 'ketalization' and use only 'acetalization' for both, am I wrong ? Btw could you update your image with something matching my reaction please? It would help me :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the term "ketal" is now out of favor.  I've added a second drawing does it help?

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/47a470c98228b6f8e46897aafac7e4c0.png whete is the second O gone ? Isn't there some H2O missing ?

Comment: Good catch, error in my drawing; fixed it. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, thank you ! I just have two more question. 1) why is this way better (energy/stability wise) to do it this way rather than using a carbocation ? 2) I've made some researches before posting my question here and didn't find any answer, where do you know it from ? (or is it just the answer you naturally came with when you thought about it?). It's not that I don't believe you, but I always feel better when I have additional sources other than just Q&A websites, especially in chemistry. :)

Comment: 1) In the top line of my drawing, the second structure from the left is an oxonium ion.  It has a resonance structure with positive charge on the carbon.  So it has some carbonium ion character, but it is not a full-fledged carbonium ion.  No carbonium ion rearrangements are observed - maybe because much of the positive charge resides on the oxygen. 2) I understand.  It is the way I learned things.  You've seen addition-elimination reactions with carbon-carbon double bonds.  Well in this case the only difference is that it involves a carbon-oxygen double bond.

Comment: Oh wow.  I totally misunderstood the original question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an SN1-like process, the intermediate is an alyoxonium ion (R1R2C=O+R), which, having a double-bond resonance form is a somewhat better intermediate than a free carbocation, as in the tradition SN1.

There is too much steric hinderance for this to be a SN2 reaction with a reasonable reaction rate.  That's a definite no-go.

Comment: The carbocation is (R1)(R2)C-OR with a lacunary central C, how is that equivalent to a (R1)(R2)C=OR structure ?

Comment: Resonances forms involving donating a lone pair from the oxygen to the carbocation forms a double bond

Comment: I got it now with @ron 's drawings, thank you :)